# allow display and or execution of web files but not direct url access using htaccess

Tags: regular-expression, htaccess

**What I want to Achieve is:**

I want to be able to display the (`mp4` | `jpg` | `ico`) file types and execute the (`js` | `css`) file types on the browser only on my domain but I dont want them to directly access those files thru typing the URL on browser address bar.

**What I expect and done is**

Being familiar with PHP `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, I get a URL like http://domainname.xyz/main.php but I do not know if the same goes with `.htaccess`. Because with `.htaccess`, the `HTTP_REFERER`, uses a regex pattern like `^https?://(www.)?domainname\.xyz/.*$` but if I use the pattern the URL as `https?://(www.)?domainname\.xyz/main.php` that I can hard code that exact URL on `.htaccess`. Such URL causes error thus I followed the code from sites and incorporated those to my script. I am not expert on htaccess regex.

**So I have the .htaccess below as researched result and followed from various sites:**

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www.)?domainname\.xyz/.*$ [NC]
 RewriteRule \.(jpg|js|css|mp4)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Also I tried using the code below followed from various sites too:

```
SetEnvIf Referer "!^https?://(www.)?domainname\.xyz/.*$" localreferer
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|js|css|mp4)$">
    Require env localreferer
</FilesMatch>
```

**What is currently happening with the above code is:**

With the above `.htaccess` scripts, only the `mp4` file types is displayed on the browser and cannot be directly access using thru the URL on the browser address bar and showing `403 Forbidden` error.

All other files types are displayed/executed on the browser and they are also directly accessed on the address bar using the URL.

**Help**

I seek your help on this because I am not an expert on htaccess, regex.  I have researched for days now and still no fix.  With your help, it will add to my knowledge.

Comment: It's not possible. In order for a browser to execute files, the files have to be downloaded by said browser. Which means, one can download said files by browsing to the correct url. A way around that might be having acitve content be executed on your server and have the server deliver the complete html-page.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is impossible. To execute a JavaScript program, or apply a CSS format file, your browser has to download these. That is *exactly* the same mechanism that is used to open a URL as typed in URL bar of your browser.

Also, even if it weren't the same method of getting the data: The browser *has* to get the data, somehow. That moment it's in the computer of your user, and thus out of your server's control.

You will have to face that fact: Websites, the embedded JS and CSS, are programs that run on your user's computers. For that, they get these things from your server. No way around that.

Comment: Well, apply your cognitive abilities to what I said, especially in the last paragraph.

Comment: Ok, then let's look at it: why would an MP4 file, to a webserver, be any different than a JS file? (do a little mental transfer here. You already have an answer here – you just need to apply it.)

Comment: yes, but that's completely irrelevant. So, what difference does that make in terms of that the data needs to get from server to browser for the browser to have it? Seriously, take a step back.

Comment: css and js needs to be downloaded and video and image file need not . yeah, currently my video files are displayed and blocked to resource but why is it not working with image files? I am puzzled because my research on web on how to prevent hotlinking to image files have the same .htaccess codes.

Comment: why do you think they need not be downloaded? Like, through which other magical way do they appear at the user's computer?

Comment: that I don't have an answer. that I also want to know why. please do teach me why.

Comment: it's simply not true. They need to be downloaded. I mean, I've alluded to this now in my answer and in 4 comments, so it's time to take the conclusion-finding out of your hands: What you assume is wrong. If a file is needed on the client, then the client needs to be able to access it, and that's always done through the same HTTP requests, no matter whether you manually type in the URL in the browser or whether it's loaded through a link, `src=` attribute in a HTML file, or whatever other mechanism.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148507/discussion-between-genesis-lubrigas-and-marcus-muller).

Comment: No, sorry. I really exhausted my explaining-carefully-and-kindly potential for today

Comment: I just mean, if you are suggesting not to use .htaccess for such goal ?

Comment: No. I'm sorry. I've explained this now. What you want is impossible, and I don't think I can say this any more clearly then how I've said it. I will not further react to this here.

Answer (score 0):

To correct your started path for a solution, my first guess goes to change your regex:

```
\.(jpg|js|css|mp4)($|\?|&)
```

Due to lack of information (see my last comment [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/756417/573955)) I can only guess about the real URIs that will be requested.

Preferably you should choose the `FileMatch`-variant.

---

But note *"Blocking by Referer" is no real securing*. The referer can automatically be manipulated by the browser or its add-on:
[image]

If you expect absolute protection, I can only say that *Marcus Müller* and *rathier* are right when saying absolute protection is impossible. You can only increase the efforts to extract the real URI to the file or limit the audience by user access control or cryptographic solutions, i.e. DRM.